# File uploading(list attachment) not working for the second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, sharepoint-2013, attachment

I am not able to upload second file into my sharepoint list(Attachment).However the first file is getting uploaded properly as an attachment in the list.I have used all the neccessory references also.The code breaks at this line:

```
 $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.RequestExecutor.js", function ()
```

the error is coming in interner explorer and not in chrome.The error is as follows:`Sys.InvalidOperationException: Type SP.PostMessageRequestInfo has already been registered. The type may be defined multiple times or the script file that defines it may have already been loaded. A possible cause is a change of settings during a partial update.`
Can anybody please tell what is the issue.

I am referring To this [link](http://%20https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51320.uploading-attachment-to-the-new-item-on-list-using-rest-api-jquery.aspx)

```
<script src="..SiteAssets/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
 <script src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>


 <script type="text/javascript" src='../SiteAssets/js/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>


 <script type="text/javascript" src="../SiteAssets/js/jquery.multifile.js"> 
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../SiteAssets/js/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
// var oLoader; 
var attcount = 0; 
var arraycount = 0; 
    $(document).ready(function ($) { 
       $('#file_input').multifile();//For facilitate multi file upload 

    $("#NewSaveItem").click(function () { formSave() }); 

}); 


function formSave() { 
     //   oLoader = SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose("Working on it", "Creating New Bank Account..."); 


            var data = []; 
            var fileArray = []; 
            $("#attachFilesHolder input:file").each(function () { 
                if ($(this)[0].files[0]) { 
                    fileArray.push({ "Attachment": $(this)[0].files[0] }); 
                } 
            }); 
        arraycount += fileArray.length;
            data.push({ 

                "City": $("input[title= City]").val(), 

                "Files": fileArray 
            }); 
            createNewItemWithAttachments("DocUploadTest", data).then( 
                function () { 
                  //  if (oLoader.close) setTimeout(function () { oLoader.close(); window.location.replace(_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/Lists/BankDetails/AllItems.aspx"); }, 3000); 

                }, 
                function (sender, args) { 
                    console.log('Error occured' + args.get_message()); 
                } 
            ) 


    } 


var createNewItemWithAttachments = function (listName, listValues) { 
    var fileCountCheck = 0; 
    var fileNames; 
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 
    var dfd = $.Deferred(); 
    var targetList = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listName); 
    context.load(targetList); 
    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation(); 
    var listItem = targetList.addItem(itemCreateInfo); 


    listItem.set_item("City", listValues[0].City); 

    listItem.update(); 
    context.executeQueryAsync( 
        function () { 
            var id = listItem.get_id(); 
            if (listValues[0].Files.length != 0) { 
                if (fileCountCheck <= listValues[0].Files.length - 1) { 
                    loopFileUpload(listName, id, listValues, fileCountCheck).then( 
                        function () { 
                        }, 
                        function (sender, args) { 
                            console.log("Error uploading"); 
                            dfd.reject(sender, args); 
                        } 
                    ); 
                } 
            } 
            else { 
                dfd.resolve(fileCountCheck); 
            } 
        }, 
        function (sender, args) { 
            console.log('Error occured' + args.get_message()); 
        } 
    ); 
    return dfd.promise(); 
} 

function loopFileUpload(listName, id, listValues, fileCountCheck) { 
    var dfd = $.Deferred(); 
    uploadFileHolder(listName, id, listValues[0].Files[fileCountCheck].Attachment).then( 
        function (data) { 
            var objcontext = new SP.ClientContext(); 
            var targetList = objcontext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listName); 
            var listItem = targetList.getItemById(id); 
            objcontext.load(listItem); 
            objcontext.executeQueryAsync(function () { 
                console.log("Reload List Item- Success"); 
                fileCountCheck++; 
                if (fileCountCheck <= listValues[0].Files.length - 1) { 
                    loopFileUpload(listName, id, listValues, fileCountCheck); 
                } else { 
                    console.log(fileCountCheck + ": Files uploaded"); 
                    attcount += fileCountCheck; 
                    if (arraycount == attcount) { 
                      //  if (oLoader.close) setTimeout(function () { oLoader.close(); window.location.replace(_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/Lists/BankDetails/AllItems.aspx"); }, 3000); 
                    } 

                } 
            }, 
            function (sender, args) { 
                console.log("Reload List Item- Fail" + args.get_message()); 
            }); 

        }, 
        function (sender, args) { 
            console.log("Not uploaded"); 
            dfd.reject(sender, args); 
        } 
   ); 
    return dfd.promise(); 
} 

function uploadFileHolder(listName, id, file) { 
    var deferred = $.Deferred(); 
    var fileName = file.name; 
    getFileBuffer(file).then( 
        function (buffer) { 
            var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer); 
            var binary = ''; 
            for (var b = 0; b < bytes.length; b++) { 
                binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[b]); 
            } 
            var scriptbase = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_layouts/15/"; 
            console.log(' File size:' + bytes.length); 
            $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.RequestExecutor.js", function () { 
                var createitem = new SP.RequestExecutor(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl); 
                createitem.executeAsync({ 
                    url: _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + listName + "')/items(" + id + ")/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='" + file.name + "')", 
                    method: "POST", 
                    binaryStringRequestBody: true, 
                    body: binary, 
                    success: fsucc, 
                    error: ferr, 
                    state: "Update" 
                }); 
                function fsucc(data) { 
                    console.log(data + ' uploaded successfully'); 
                    deferred.resolve(data); 
                } 
                function ferr(data) { 
                    console.log(fileName + "not uploaded error"); 
                    deferred.reject(data); 
                } 
            }); 

        }, 
        function (err) { 
            deferred.reject(err); 
        } 
    ); 
    return deferred.promise(); 
} 
function getFileBuffer(file) { 
    var deferred = $.Deferred(); 
    var reader = new FileReader(); 
    reader.onload = function (e) { 
        deferred.resolve(e.target.result); 
    } 
    reader.onerror = function (e) { 
        deferred.reject(e.target.error); 
    } 
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file); 
    return deferred.promise(); 
}
```

html code:

```
City :<input type="text" value=""  id="City" title="City">
 <span style="font-family: " segoe ui" ,sans-serif; color: #444444">Click 
 here to attach file</span> <div class="files" id="attachFilesHolder"> 
 <input id="file_input" type="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple"> 
                                </div> 
 <input name="SaveItem" style=" height: 40px; font-size: 15px;" class="ms-ButtonHeightWidth" id="NewSaveItem" accesskey="O" onclick="" type="button" value="Click here to submit " target="_self">
</html>
```

Console output:

```
 File size:63
 [object Object] uploaded successfully
 Reload List Item- Success
 File size:4
```